# How to automatically include C++ headers in vim?

Tags: c++, vim

Often I want to use STL functions and containers and I find myself having to add manually:

```
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
```

to the beginning of the file. Is anyone aware of a vim plugin or command line program that will do that sort of thing automatically?

Comment: Maintain a template of the #includes and other functions that you think are useful to programs. Write a small script in bash, so that it copies the template when you create the new file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a pretty uphill battle once you start to want some fancy IDE behavior from vim, especially once it requires code parsing.

You should decide what's more important to you, using vim as an editor, or getting coding assistance. If the former is more important to you, stick with vim; otherwise, consider getting a decent IDE such as [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) or [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/) to name a few.

Both NetBeans and Eclipse have plugins that emulate vim to some degree.
NetBeans has:

- [jvi](http://jvi.sourceforge.net/) - overall supports a lot of vi functionality, but is quite buggy from the brief amount of testing I have done with it (for example sometimes it says you are in normal mode but as you type keys you realize you aren't and you have to restart to fix it.)

Eclipse has:

- [vrapper](http://vrapper.sourceforge.net/home/) - overall pretty solid implementation, but has annoying bugs (when refactoring code it sometimes causes exceptions and the refactoring to fail, so far haven't found a work around for it.) It's an abandoned project too it seems.
- [eclim](http://eclim.org) - active project that lets you run Eclipse in vim (it's a vim plugin that adds some Eclipse functionality to vim by running Eclipse as a server) OR it lets you run vim in Eclipse (but then you loose all the built in Eclipse functionality which might defeat the purpose.) From having used it, it works pretty well, but it starts to get hairy when adding new files and code to the project, sometimes it doesn't seem to reindex your project properly and nothing short of loading Eclipse and forcing Eclipse to reindex the project seems to work. Also, as a note, this plugin for vim would not accomplish what you want because they have not implemented that feature of Eclipse
- [viplugin](http://www.viplugin.com/viplugin/) - pretty solid implementation of vim functionality. Free to try but costs about $20. The maintainer has sporadic updates. Try it and see if you like it.
- [viable](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/viable-vim-eclipse) - one of the more solid plugins for emulating vim functionality within Eclipse. After having tried all the other options I am currently sticking to using this one in the trail mode, the plugin is pay ($15), so I get annoying pop ups every X amount of time. Will be buying it if I keep using it for much longer.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have been using vim because I find vim as an editor more important than the rest of the IDE. I have used jvi and eclim. I like jvi better than eclim, although it still lacks important features. The feature of those IDEs I miss the most is the auto-include (actually I've used it for java, never for C++). So I'm trying to get into the ideal world, where I can use the best features of both worlds :P

Comment: You need an IDE to add text to the beginning of a file? Vim is not enough for that?

Answer (score 6):

You first need to write a .cpp file that will include all the headers that you generallly require.

Mine looks something like this,

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

typedef long long int ll;

int main(void) {

return 0;
}
```

Now add this line to your vimrc file,

```
autocmd BufNewFile *.cpp r /path/to/template.cpp
```

Now every time you will open a .cpp file you will have everything you need prewritten.

Answer (score 5):

Probably, but I wouldn't recommend it. And `#include <vector>` isn't that hard to type at all.

Perhaps you start too many projects you don't finish or use too many different files?

And finally, more a preference thing, I prefer to use `std::vector` over `vector`, because then I'm sure what I mean, namely the standard vector.

**You seem to be a beginner that thinks you can save time with `using namespace std;` & co, but trust me, you don't.** <sub>Please don't take this as offense, just a tip.</sub>

Comment: I'd hardly say just because he uses `using namespace std;` means he is a beginner .... There are plenty of reasons why you may want to use that, and saving typing time while sacrificing readability is completely legit...

Comment: @ldog: I strongly disagree with you. `using namespace std;` has many consequences, of which a few wanted.

Comment: My rule of thumb is: in interfaces never use `using namespace X` as your forcing onto the user of your interface something they may not expect, but in implementation file only you need to know about using namespace is ok.

Comment: I include in my namespace only the names I'm going to use. Like std::vector in that case. I find it much better to read, specially when using iterators and passing multiple STL parameters. I don't use it on headers, only .cc files for obvious reasons.

Anyway, that's beside the point. I don't want to change the way I program, merely make it easier to import what I need.

Comment: BTW, for STL iterators you can use auto now in C++0x

Comment: Why wouldn't you recommend it? In almost every file I write in C++ I have to include `cstdlib`, `iostream`, and `vector`. Why shouldn't my editor automatically add that, plus an empty int main (int argc, char** argv)? And why shouldn't I use `using namespace std` on standalone programs for my own use?

Answer (score 2):

I used to use the following four keyboard mappings in my .vimrc before I started using emacs:

```
nmap _i I<C-m><Esc>kI#include ""<Esc>$i
imap <C-z>i <Esc>_i
nmap _I I<C-m><Esc>kI#include <><Esc>$i
imap <C-z><C-i> <Esc>_I
```

The first one, <kbd>_</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> in command mode inserts `#include ""` to the line above, and leaves the cursor inside the quotes in insert mode. The second is the same for insert mode, but I have no idea why I used <kbd>CTRL-Z</kbd> as the command prefix. The second pair is for system headers. You use <kbd>I</kbd> instead of <kbd>i</kbd> to get that one.

I would recommend using something that you can use in more places instead of a dedicated one for vectors only, but you can easily change the ones above to have a keyboard map for inserting the snippet you need.

Answer (score 2):

```
" the sixth line contains a model
augroup lang_cpp
    au!
    au BufNewFile,BufRead *.cpp set ft=cpp   
    au FileType cpp set omnifunc=omni#cpp#complete#Main
    au FileType cpp let OmniCpp_MayCompleteScope = 0 
    au BufNewFile *.cpp 0r ~/.vim/skel/cpp.skel
au
```

Answer (score 1):

[lh-cpp](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp/) snippets can automatically include required headers. For instance, if you complete on `vect`, you'll see `std::vector<|>` expanded, and `#include <vector>` added if not yet already included.

However, at his point it isn't able to see that `<vector>` has already been included in another included file.

Answer (score 0):

I have found 3 vim plugins to include c++ headers automatically.

- [cpp_auto_include.vim](https://github.com/quark-zju/vim-cpp-auto-include/blob/master/plugin/cpp_auto_include.vim)
- [cpp_includer.vim](https://github.com/qdore/vim-cpp-includer/blob/master/plugin/cpp_includer.vim)
- [autoincludex.vim](https://github.com/vim-scripts/autoincludex.vim/blob/master/plugin/autoincludex.vim)

Comment: FWIW, none of these three use tags which would make them easier to use on code you're writing. Instead they have their own ways of generating a mapping from symbol to file: vim-cpp-auto-include uses ruby and I think just for stdlib, autoincludex has the user fill in headers (and remembers), cpp-includer has a [config file of mappings](https://github.com/qdore/vim-cpp-includer/blob/master/plugin/cpp_includer.cfg).

Answer (score 0):

This vim plugin named [vim-cpp-auto-include](https://github.com/quark-zju/vim-cpp-auto-include) will fit your need.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).